# Converting float to double only when function's prototype is not specified

Tags: c

I've been learning the C language the other day and discovered the "function prototypes" concept.

Basically, if you want to call a function before it's definition, the practice is to specify the parameters and returning type of function.

Then I tried following code (without prototype), and it worked, because GCC could work out the function's signature.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", my_print(123123));
}

int my_print(int a)
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 456;
}

//code works
```

However, that code does not compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", my_print(123123.0f));
}

int my_print(float a)
{
    printf("%f\n", a);
    return 456;
}
//code DOES NOT compile
```

Even further, code below compiles and runs smoothly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", my_print((float) 123123.0f));
}

int my_print(double a)
{
    printf("%f\n", a);
    return 456;
}
//code compiles 0_o
```

Lastly, when you specify function's signature, compiler now wants to see parameter in "float" type.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_print(float a);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", my_print((float) 123123.0f));
}

int my_print(float a)
{
    printf("%f\n", a);
    return 456;
}
//code compiles
```

So, the question is, why the hell compiler wants to convert float to double only when function's prototype is not specified?

Comment: The errors/warnings issued during your compiles are nothing if not highly relevant, and should be included *verbatim* with your question.

Comment: The real question is, why the heck would you try to call a function without first providing the function prototype (or the function definition)?

Comment: The reality is that calling a function without providing a prototype is actually possible in this language. The real question is: why such strange behavior with automatic type conversion occurs?

Comment: `int` is the default type assumed by the compiler for arguments and return value. Any other type is liable to confuse the compiler, and in modern C declarations are required. Not giving them is a concession for backward compatabilty.

Comment: Note too that `double` is the default floating point type assumed by the compiler.  As always, don't ask "why did my program work when I broke the rules."

Comment: Igor Chovpan, "However, that code does not compile:" implies you are not using a C compiler.  What compiler are you using?  Please post the compiler error message.

Comment: yup, using gcc compiler on Ubuntu Mate 20.04, 64-bit system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the effect of the *default argument promotions*, which apply (a) in the variable-length part of variable-length argument lists, and (b) when a function is called *without* a prototype in scope.  The default argument promotions say that, basically, anything smaller than `int` is promoted to `int`, and `float` is promoted to `double`.

When C was new and when function prototypes hadn't been invented yet, these rules kept the calling conventions simpler and the compiler smaller.

Today, with function prototypes more or less universally in place, these rules are almost unnecessary and almost forgotten, although they are perhaps even more confusing than they were back in the day, because they do still show up in the variable-length part of variable-length argument lists, and account for quirks like the asymmetry of `%f` and `%lf` between `printf` and `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to 1972. Calling a function without a prototype is OK because there is no other choice. Prototypes do not exist yet. They will be invented a decade or so later by one Bjarne Stroustrup for his newfangled C++ language. They will prove so darn good that C will have no excuse not to steal the idea. Functions with no prototype will ve allowed for long, long, long time after that, but they will be discouraged and eventually hopefully deprecated and removed from the language altogether at some date after year 2021.

So why does the compiler do weird things when a prototype is not specified? Because they were not weird when prototypes did not exist, and they are not going to change just because a better way exists now. If the language did not stipulate promotion of float to double, it would be all too easy to commit a silent, hard-to-find error by calling a function that needs a double argument with a float parameter. It is a simple protection against this particular class of errors. The language limits the choice of argument types. If you cannot pass a float because it is immediately promoted to double, then you cannot pass a float by mistake when a double is expected.

These considerations are mostly irrelevant today. All new code should use prototypes, or be shredded and sent to /dev/null. However there is still one relevant case when this promotion applies, namely variadic functions (e.g. printf). In these functions, some of the argument types are not specified in the prototype, so the language still partially guards against erroneous argument types.